# Time series decomposition fails with "time series has no or less than 2 periods"

Tags: r, datetime, time-series, posixct

I have a dataframe with a column data (double) and a column date (S3: POSIXct).
I created a new variable :

```r
bdd$datats <- ts(data = bdd$data, frequency = 12)
```

I then tried to apply the function decompose

```r
decomp <- decompose(bdd$datats, type = "multiplicative")
decomp$figure
```

As it doesn't work I don't understand why. Can someone explain me?

Comment: How much data do you have? Do you have more than 24 points?

Comment: Hello @Estelle Ursula. Welcome on SO! Please add a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) so that other SO users can help you in the best way. Besides, it would be useful to include the error message you get. Cheers.